# google-chrome fails to start with selenium in flask app

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I have a python script that runs with selenium and Chrome in a flask app. It works well on my Mac.
I am now trying to run it on an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and am facing some issues. When run outside of the app, the same code works. However, when it runs within the app (using the same virtual environment) Chrome fails to start with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=options,service_args=service_args, service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

The selenium error is:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`

and chrome logs are:

```
[1549386746.673][INFO]: Launching chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-gpu --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --headless --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.n9eYGc/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.9VhG53 --window-size=1920,1080 data:,
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 8: readlink: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 10: dirname: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: exec: cat: not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: exec: cat: not found
[1549386746.732][INFO]: [d94921c851f9c0a2faa7428e62501aca] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
[1549386746.735][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[1549386746.735][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

Here is `echo $PATH`

`/home/user/folder/project/site-env/site/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/bin:/bin`

I would very much appreciate some insight into why chrome doesn't find readlink, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was eventually resolved by adding:

`export PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin"` to  chrome executable (`/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`).

The flask app is running under a different user that seems to have no path.